# Creating pandas dataframe from series changes indexes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, series

I have two series that are indexed in the same format.  Here are clips of the two below (because of the size of the data I won't show the entire set):

```
>>> s1
Out[52]: 
parameter_id  parameter_type_cs_id
4959          1                        -0.2664122
4960          1                      -0.004289398
4961          1                      -0.006652875
4966          1                      -0.004208685
4967          1                       -0.02268688
4968          1                       -0.05958452
4969          1                       -0.01133198
4970          1                       -0.01968251
4972          1                       -0.05860331
4974          1                       -0.08260008
4975          1                       -0.05402012
4979          1                        -0.0308407
4980          1                       -0.02232495
4987          1                        -0.2315813
4990          1                       -0.02171027
...
727241        1                            -0.00156766
727242        1                          -0.0009964491
727243        1                           -0.007068732
727244        1                           -0.003500738
727245        1                           -0.006572505
727246        1                          -0.0005814131
728060        1                             -0.0144799
728062        1                             -0.0418521
728063        1                            -0.01367948
728065        1                            -0.03625054
728066        1                            -0.06806824
728068        1                           -0.007910916
728071        1                           -0.005482052
728073        1                           -0.005845178
intercept                             [-11.4551819018]
Name: coef, Length: 1529, dtype: object

>>> s2
Out[53]: 
parameter_id  parameter_type_cs_id
4958          1                       -0.001683882
4959          1                          -1.009859
4960          1                      -0.0004456379
4961          1                       -0.005564386
4963          1                         -0.9145955
4964          1                      -0.0009077246
4965          1                      -0.0003179153
4966          1                      -0.0006907124
4967          1                        -0.02125838
4968          1                        -0.02443978
4969          1                       -0.002665334
4970          1                       -0.003135213
4971          1                      -0.0003539563
4972          1                        -0.03684852
4973          1                      -0.0001203596
...
728044        1                          -0.0003084855
728060        1                              -0.925618
728061        1                           -0.001192743
728062        1                             -0.9203911
728063        1                           -0.002522615
728064        1                          -0.0003572484
728065        1                           -0.003475959
728066        1                            -0.02329697
728068        1                           -0.001412785
728069        1                           -0.002095895
728070        1                          -9.790675e-05
728071        1                          -0.0003013977
728072        1                          -0.0003369116
728073        1                           -0.000249748
intercept                             [-12.1281459287]
Name: coef, Length: 1898, dtype: object
```

The index formats are the same and so I try to put them into a dataframe like so:

```
d = {'s1': s1, 's2': s2}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

However I notice that the output has almost all `NaN` which I find shocking.  I looked at the indexes for the individual series and noticed that the dataframe had them as strings instead of the same format as the series

```
>>> s1.index.values
Out[54]: 
array([(4959, 1), (4960, 1), (4961, 1), ..., (728071, 1), (728073, 1),
       ('intercept', '')], dtype=object)

>>> s2.index.values
Out[55]: 
array([(4958, 1), (4959, 1), (4960, 1), ..., (728072, 1), (728073, 1),
       ('intercept', '')], dtype=object)
```

But the dataframe has strings

```
>>> df.index.values
Out[56]: 
array([('4959', '1'), ('4960', '1'), ('4961', '1'), ..., ('8666', '1'),
       ('9638', '1'), ('intercept', '')], dtype=object)
```

Why is it changing the type and is that causing my problem...?

Even more bizarre to me is if I try the same as above on a smaller set I see the behavior I would expect (not all `NaN` and the indexes aren't converted)

```
s1_ = s1[:15]
s2_ = s2[:15]
d_ = {'s1': s1_, 's2': s2_}
df_ = pd.DataFrame(d_) #<---- This has the behavior I would expect
```

**EDIT**
I have found a way that works but I'm not sure why it works like this, if I convert both series into dataframes then join them it works as expected:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'s1': s1})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'s2': s2})
new_df = df_1.join(df_2) #WHY DOES THIS WAY WORK!?!?
```

Comment: Can you try: `pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1, keys=["s1", "s2"])`

Comment: @HYRY I get the same result unfortunately...all NaN values and string indexes

Comment: It seems to me that your data has 3 (4959, 1, -1.009859)values and two column headings (parameter_id  parameter_type_cs_id). Is that your intention. The reason you are seeing index as an array is probably because of this discrepency

Comment: @nitin I'm sorry I don't quite follow you, looking back I only see two entries indexed by (4959, 1).  One in each series.  And when I try to combine them into a dataframe they would be under separate columns with separate names

Comment: what pandas version are you using?

Comment: can you get a reproducible example, without that it's difficult to solve!

Comment: Also, what version of Pandas are you using? `pd.__version__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it is converting the indexes to strings is because the last index

```
intercept                             [-11.4551819018]
```

in your series data is a string. The documentation for the Pandas data frames state that when constructing a data frame from a series the data frame keeps the same indexing from the series which causes the conversion to all strings because of the last line in the data.

Your solution to create two data frames and then joining them works because the indexing is consistent since you're using the same data structure (e.g. data frame) rather than converting from one data structure (series) to another (data frame). It seems to be a Pandas specific thing. I would stick with your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have your dataframe, but here's an example with small data to show that pandas contructs the dataframe as expected (using pandas 0.15.1 and python 3.4). As expected, NaNs are introduced when the indices don't match.

The last row of your data is ('intercept', ''), while all the other rows are numbers. So ('intercept', '') goes to the index of each series, and this is probably causing the values in the index to be "promoted" to strings.

```
>> s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)], names=['a','b']))
>>> s1
a  b
1  1    1
   2    2
   3    3
dtype: int64
>>> s2 = pd.Series([100,200,300], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)], names=['a','b']))
>>> 
>>> s2
a  b
1  2    100
   3    200
   4    300
dtype: int64
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1, 's2':s2})
>>> df
     s1   s2
a b         
1 1   1  NaN
  2   2  100
  3   3  200
  4 NaN  300
>>> df.index.values
array([(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], dtype=object)
```